# Which Ubuntu to use alongside Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, samsung

I have an old Samsung N148 Plus netbook (Intel Atom 1.66GHz, 1GB RAM, 250GB). I want to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 7 Home Premium.

Any Ideas as to what flavor or what version of Ubuntu to install?

Comment: **ubuntu mate**, **lubuntu**, **xubuntu**, and **ubuntustudio** are all good for netbooks.